# SFTP user permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp

I have created a new sftpuser with below format.

```
sudo adduser --shell /bin/false sftpuser
sudo passwd sftpuser
sudo mkdir -p /var/sftp/files


sudo chown sftpuser:sftpuser /var/sftp/files
sudo chown root:root /var/sftp
sudo chmod 755 /var/sftp
```

After that I have edited the sshd file (`sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`)as below,

```
Match User sftpuser
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /var/sftp
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

But still I couldnt sftp to my server. Always getting below error.

```
Permission denied, please try again
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: What command are you using to connect?

Comment: sftp sftpuser@XX.XXX.XX.XX

Comment: Have you tried sftp -v to see if it gives you any clues?